# Record not insert into the database using laravel 8 ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

i am a begineer of laravel and ajax i can do the system well in core php. i just converted to laravel.
i creating simple crud using laravel with ajax but i don't know how call the path through ajax request. what i tried so fat i attached below.pls give me the solution for it.

Screen shot of folder structure

[image]

this is view part. i name it

**list.blade.php**

```
div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form class="card" id="frmProject">
           
            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                <label class="form-label">First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="first_name" id="first_name" name="first_name" size="30px"  required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                <label class="form-label">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="last_name" id="last_name" name="last_name" size="30px"  required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                <label class="form-label">Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" id="address" name="address" size="30px"  required>

            </div>
           


            <div class="card" align="right">
                <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-info" onclick="addProject()">Add</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

**Ajax Call**

```
function addProject() {
    if ($("#frmProject").valid())
    {
        var _url = '';
        var _data = '';
        var _method;
        if (isNew == true) {
            _url = '/student';
         
            _data = $('#frmProject').serialize();
            _method = 'POST';
        }
        else {
            _url = '/student',
                _data = $('#frmProject').serialize() + "&project_id=" + project_id;
            _method = 'POST';

            alert(project_id);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: _method,
            url: _url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: _data,
            beforeSend: function () {

                $('#save').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#save').html('');
                $('#save').append('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw"></i>Saving</i>');


            },
            success: function (data) {

                $('#frmProject')[0].reset();
                $('#save').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#save').html('');
                $('#save').append('Add');
                get_all();
                var msg;
                console.log(data);
                if (isNew)
                {
                    msg="Brand Created";
                }
                else{
                    msg="Brand Updated";
                }
                $.alert({
                    title: 'Success!',
                    content: msg,
                    type: 'green',
                    boxWidth: '400px',
                    theme: 'light',
                    useBootstrap: false,
                    autoClose: 'ok|2000'


                });
                isNew = true;
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);

                $.alert({
                    title: 'Fail!',
                                content: xhr.responseJSON.errors.product_code + '<br>' + xhr.responseJSON.msg,
                    type: 'red',
                    autoClose: 'ok|2000'

                });
                $('#save').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#save').html('');
                $('#save').append('Save');

            }

        });


    }
}
```

**Student Controller**

```
class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        
        $data['students'] = Student::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(5);   
        return view('student.list',$data);
    }
 
    public function create()
    {
       
    }
  
    public function store(Request $request)
    {       
        $student = new Student([
            'first_name' => $request->post('first_name'),
        'last_name'=> $request->post('lastname'),
        'address'=> $request->post('address')
    ]);
        ]);
        $student->save();    
        return Response::json($student);
    }
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('student', [App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('student', [App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'store'])->name('student.store');
```

Comment: is there an error or something? what is actually happening?

Comment: through console i checked Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status)
student:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received

Comment: 419 is usually a CSRF token mismatch

Comment: shall i put into github

Comment: you are not sending the CSRF token with the request you are making

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
    });  this line have add it

Comment: i did it sir it won't work

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".btn-submit").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var pswd = $("#pwd").val();
                var address = $("#address").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "url",
                    type:'POST',
                    data: {_token:_token, email:email, pswd:pswd,address:address},
                    success: function(data) {
                      printMsg(data);
                    }
                });
            }); 

            function printMsg (msg) {
              if($.isEmptyObject(msg.error)){
                  console.log(msg.success);
                  $('.alert-block').css('display','block').append('<strong>'+msg.success+'</strong>');
              }else{
                $.each( msg.error, function( key, value ) {
                  $('.'+key+'_err').text(value);
                });
              }
            }
        });
```

Please use csrf token